# Timers eating memory (3MB for second)

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, timer

I have application written on c# and which uses few timers (4 Timers).The application request responses from web service by relevant time intervals.if internet is connected application use 12-15 Mb of memory but when internet is disconnected application increasing memory usage (3MB per second).

I force run garbage collector but no improvement.
when internet is disconnects occurs some exceptions but all of them are properly handled.

this is part of my code if internet is disconnectd and when calling shn.show*Details() methods increases memory usage  GetXML.GetResponce () does that call webservice on paramitter and return reply xml as string, ParseXML class does above returned xml respnce parse and convert it to a object

```
class Scheduler
{
    private System.Windows.Forms.Timer dataTimer;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Timer promoTimer;
    private showNotifications shn;
    public Scheduler()
    {

        dataTimer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
        promoTimer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
        shn = new showNotifications();
    }

    public void scheduleDmsg(int time)
    {
        if (time < 1)
        { time = 5; }
        dataTimer.Interval = time * 60000;
        dataTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(InitDmsg);
        dataTimer.Enabled = true;
    }

    public void schedulePmsg(int time)
    {
        if (time < 1)
        { time = 5; }
        promoTimer.Interval = time * 60000;
        promoTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(InitPmsg);
        promoTimer.Enabled = true;
    }

    private void InitDmsg(Object source, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            //--------------------at the start of app------------------
            showNotifications shn = new showNotifications();
            HandleUserData hud = new HandleUserData();
            Userinfo uin = hud.ReadUserData();

            XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();

            xmlDoc.InnerXml = GetXML.GetResponse(new Uri("auth service url"));// this web service use to authenticate user by ip address
            Auth authDetails = ParseXML.ParseAuth(xmlDoc);

            try
            {
                if (authDetails.SUB.Equals("no_entry")) // if authenicated no_entry become >> <11 digit number>
                { }
                else
                {
                    //if authenticated
                    xmlDoc.InnerXml = GetXML.GetResponse(new Uri("info url"));
                    Pre preDetails = ParseXML.ParsePre(xmlDoc);

                    switch (preDetails.SUB_TYPE)
                    {
                        case "1":
                            shn.showPreDetails(); //showPreDetails method display some information on cusom notification message
                            break;
                        case "2":
                            shn.showPostDetails();//showPostDetails method display some information on cusom notification message
                            break;
                        case "3":
                            shn.showPreDetails();
                            break;
                        case "4":
                            shn.showPreDetails();
                            break;
                        case "5":
                            shn.showPostDetails();

                            break;
                        default:
                            break;

                    }

                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //MessageBox.Show("Error Occured");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }



    }
    private void InitPmsg(Object source, EventArgs e)
    {
        //shn.showPromoMsgs();
        showNotifications.showPromoMsgs(); ////showPromoDetails method display some information on cusom notification message
    }
}
```

Comment: You'll have to post some code for us to see what's going on. Most likely, you have a memory leak caused by dangling references to objects. And forcing the GC to run isn't going to fix that.

Comment: How often/when do you the method 'scheduleDmsg'? It subscribes to the Tick event on each call. Does anything release the subscription?

Comment: scheduleDmsg and schedulePmsg are call for one time,in the application's form_load.

Comment: Please mark as answer if you were helped in any way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a windows service connecting to Tibco every minute, listening on the queue for messages, this connection was never properly closed and therefore you keep on utilizing more memory for every connection opened. You have to force a disconnect.

Try and implement dispose on the following objects HandleUserData, Userinfo, Pre and Auth.

Call dispose on these objects when you're done using them in method InitDmsg.

Answer (score 1):

Are you shutting down your communication on a disconnect?  On your first disconnect you need to shutdown the communication then periodically check to see if you get reconnected and then start the connections again.